# How to get output from ls command into perl script by using unix pipe

Tags: perl, pipe

I need to take list of files and subdirectories in current directory and then take necessary actions with a perl script. The following command must be used for this purpose : `ls -F | perl myfile.pl`. The problem is how to reach output of ls command in perl script. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `chomp( @files = do { local @ARGV = "ls -F |"; <> } )`

Comment: @Shnkc why don't you just use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, simply read the Standard input of the perl script:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    print "---> $_";  # or whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing not a heavy one-liner perl script, you can use "-n" pipe flag so you don't need to loop the input :

```
ls -F | perl -ne "print $_;"
```

Comment: Even shorter: ls -F | perl -pe ""

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hand the contents of a directory to a Perl script, you're better off passing in the file names as arguments.

```
perl myscript.pl *
```

Then...

```
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    ...
}
```

This avoids having to parse the output of `ls -F` making your code simpler, faster, more robust and portable.

The types of the files can be told inside Perl using the [file test operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

```
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    if( -l $file ) {
        ...do something with a symbolic link...
    }
    elsif( -d $file ) {
        ...do something with a directory...
    }
    else {
        ...regular file...
    }
}
```

Comment: Say what‽‽‽ The BSD `ls` program has had `-F` since . . . since . . . since like before you were born! :)  I mean, seriously: it’s in my college shell alias set from like 30 years ago.  And it is quite definitely present on OpenBSD and OS X today.

Comment: @tchrist You're right about that (except possibly the before I was born part, but it's a close race there). The directory I tested BSD ls in didn't have anything interesting for `-F` to display.

Comment: I wonder whether he doesn’t just want `for my $file (glob("*")) { ... }`. Still, I prefer arguments myself.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command and process its output inside the `perl` script. It's the same behavior as a pipe.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $ls, '-|' , 'ls -F' or die;

while ( <$ls> ) { 
    ## Process each line.
}
```

Comment: Whyever would you write it that way intstead of writing `"ls -F|"`?  Isn’t that just gratuitous for no good reason?  It’s a lot easier to read and understand the other way, and doesn’t mean anything at all that’s different. Also, you forgot to close your pipehandle to fetch back the 16-bit wait status; you should always do that. How else do you know your command actually ran correctly?

Answer (score 0):

ls -F | perl myfile.pl -

We just need the "-" argument after the script name. BTW, using the "*" in place of "-" not work.